# Accept a variable number of hashsets as arguments

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script that takes a string as a first argument and then a variable number of dictionaries.

This is how the script starts:

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [string] $Identity,

    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
        ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true,
        Position = 1)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [hashtable[]] $Contacts
)
```

When I try to execute the script as below:

> .\scriptName.ps1 "alice@alice"  @{email="a"; firstName="fn"} @{email="b";firstName="fn2"}

I get the following errors:

> D:\Griffin\sources\dev\SubstrateSearch\src\TdsDeployment\SetupSubstrateSearchServices\Scripts\CreateExplicitContacts.ps1
>   : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Contacts'.
>   Cannot convert value
>   "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]" to type
>   "System.Collections.Hashtable[]". Error: "Cannot convert the
>   "alice@alice" value of type "System.String" to type
>   "System.Collections.Hashtable"." At line:1 char:1
>   + .\CreateExplicitContacts.ps1 "alice@alice"  @{email="a"; firstName="f ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [CreateExplicitContacts.ps1],
>   ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,CreateExplicitContacts.ps1

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the error I see that the script interprets alice@alice as hashtable which is not expected. try specifying position=0 for the Identity parameter or use -Identity parameter explicitly

`\scriptName.ps1 -Identity "alice@alice" @{email="a"; firstName="fn"} @{email="b";firstName="fn2"}`

Comment: It works for me after either specifying `Position = 0` for `$Identity` or removing `Position = 1` from `$Contacts`.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks a lot :) It worked.